# ¿ Como agregar un archivo pdf en html para verlo en mi web?

Tags: html, pdf

Estoy tratando de crear un apartado en mi pagina web con los estudios que tengo, que no son muchos.
Quiero mostrar los diplomas, que los tengo en PDF.
Con este código se muestra, pero pinchando en el enlace: `<a href="pdf/html.pdf">Haz clic aquí para el PDF</a>`                           Querría poder verlos directamente como si de fotos se tratase, si la hay, pues he buscado por google y no encuentro la forma.
Un saludo y muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando una de las siguientes etiquetas:

```
<object  data="archivo.pdf"></object>

<iframe  src="archivo.pdf"></iframe>
```

Aqui hay un ejemplo con iframe:
[ejemplo iframe](https://codepen.io/alxfyv/full/WxeLve/)

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probe y funciona pecfectamente. Solo añadire width y heigth par que no me salga "Scrollbar", que tampoco es mucho, pero.

Comment: Hay forma de quitar el Scrollbar...??? Resulta inutil y un poco incomodo.

Comment: En el estilo del elemento agrega overflow:hidden